# error is xmemory - c++0x support missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, c++11

I have made a winform app where i have used vectors of array[n][n] type using

```
typedef char myarray[9][9];  
typedef vector<myarray> array3d;
```

as far as i have read, this feature is provided in c++0x. I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate is the error in xmemory because of this? The ide is showing no other error exept from this (not even where the above code is)

```
'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces
```

pointing to this code in xmemory

```
void construct(pointer _Ptr, _Ty&& _Val)
    {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
    ::new ((void _FARQ *)_Ptr) _Ty(_STD forward<_Ty>(_Val));
    }
```

In a code of over 2.5 k lines how do i find where's the problem?

EDIT:

Since the problems seem with vectors here are all the operations that i do with vectors

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef char myarray[9][9];
typedef string string_array[9][9];

void function2(vector<string_array>*my_3d_string_array, int d)
{
    string::iterator it;
    int j,cl;
    it=find((*my_3d_string_array)[d][j][cl].begin(),(*my_3d_string_array)[d][j][cl].end(),3);
    (*my_3d_string_array)[d][2][3].erase(it);
}

void function(vector<string_array>*my_3d_string_array, int d)
{
    (*my_3d_string_array)[d][3][4] = 2;
    function2(my_3d_string_array,d);
}

int main()
{
    myarray matrix;
    string_array string_matrix;

    std::vector<myarray>      my_3d_array;
    std::vector<string_array> my_3d_string_array;

    // fill_matrix(matrix);
    // fill_string_matrix(string_matrix)

    int d;
    function(&my_3d_string_array, d); // passing pointer to vector to a function d is the 3rd dimention

    my_3d_array.push_back(matrix);
    my_3d_string_array.push_back(string_matrix);
}
```

is there a stupid error i am making here?

Comment: Then where is the error, and what's on that line? Also, is the vector really named `3darray`?

Comment: no - none of this is the real code. i just gave an exemplifying code.
i want to create a vector(dynamic array) of matrices (array[9][9]).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I posted my error list here: http://pastebin.com/ezYfbGAH (perhaps I reproduced a slightly different error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array types are not supported as the elements in containers.

The workaround is, probably, to use `std::array<>` instead of `char[]`

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

typedef std::array<std::array<char,4>, 6> array;
typedef std::vector<array> _3darray; 

int main()
{
    _3darray a, b;
    a = b;
}
```

- g++ 4.6 likes it
- MSVC++ 2010 doesn't likes it too :)

Comment: Worst case the OP can always use vector of a vector of a vector.

Comment: Or boost multidimensional arrays :)

Comment: i want only the third dimension to be dynamic

Comment: using array is giving more bizarre errors.. how do i do it with the given ide?

Comment: @I compiled it with VS2010 (using the _exact_ code snippet shown). You might have _another problem_ in your code

Comment: what can an error in template class _ALLOCATOR and template construct point to?

Comment: probably that you're still using decayed array types in containers. You'd have to post some actual code, I'm afraid.

Comment: Mmm. Turns out arrays are simply not valid container elements. Period. Your code helps, though it looks like you're aiming for the prize in an obfuscated code contest. See here for a usable version of that mess: http://ideone.com/5nc3m (gradually comment out offending lines to see what requirements are not met by the container element types). This would have been much clearer with **[Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B))** :(

Comment: so i cannot make matrices as vector types?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5224/discussion-between-sehe-and-aseem-dua)

Answer (score 0):

Because template types are instantiated at compile time, it is not possible to have a runtime variable participate (even indirectly) in a template argument, even with C++0x.

You may be interested in the [boost multidimensional array library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), however, which can be used to declare 3d arrays easily. Here's an example from the docs:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>

int 
main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;

  // Verify values
  int verify = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am sorry the value of n is fixed...its 9 not some variable..i was trying to make it generic.. but i supose i miscommunicated..

Comment: Did you declare it as a `#define`, or as a `const int`, or did you actually write `typedef char array[9][9]`?

Comment: Now, I got thinking, _why_ would anyone verify the assignment to array elements? Reminds me of pay-by-LOC code :)